# Derivation of the Yukawa potential by integration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, potential, plasma-physics, greens-functions, dirac-delta-distributions

I'm trying to solve the Yukawa potential using standard integration methods, but can't seem to be getting the correct result. This derivation is a part of Bellan's "Fundamentals of Plasma Physics", assignment 1.4. The aim is to solve this equation (let's call it 1.1):

$$\nabla^{2} \Phi - \frac{1}{\lambda_D^2} \Phi = -\frac{q_T}{\epsilon_0} \delta(\vec r)$$

by guessing that the solution has the form

$$ \Phi(r) = \frac{g(r)}{4\pi\epsilon_0r},$$

substituting the guess in (1.1) and solving for g(r). This calculation should result in the Yukawa potential (1.2):

$$ \Phi(r) = \frac{q_T}{4\pi\epsilon_0r} exp(\frac{-r}{\lambda_D}).$$

This should be a relatively simple exercise, but as I've substituted the solution to (1.1), I run into some problems. I can factor out the non-r dependent coefficient and multiply by epsilon, and then write the Laplacian and in spherical coordinates and simplify to get:

$$ \frac{g''(r)}{r} - \frac{1}{\lambda_D^2} \frac{g(r)}{r} = q_T 4\pi \delta(\vec r)$$

that I can solve by determining the general & particular solutions. The result I get for this equation is:

$$ g(r) = C_1 exp(\frac{-r}{\lambda_D}) + C_2 exp(\frac{r}{\lambda_D}) + \lambda_D^2 q_T 4\pi \delta(\vec r)r.$$

For this to be consistent with (1.3) I should be able to set the second coefficient equal to 0 and eliminate the delta function term, and the first coefficient should be q_T. I'm assuming this is a result of some physical qualities or delta function properties, but I can't think of any relevant boundary conditions - or perhaps my treatment of the differential equation is at fault. Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: Do not forget that $\Delta \frac{1}{4\pi r} = - \delta$, i.e. choosing $g(0)$ adequately will make the $\delta$-terms cancel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use the identity $\nabla^2(\frac{1}{r})=-4\pi\delta(\vec{r})$. In other words, substitute $\nabla^2\Phi=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0r}\nabla^2g(r)-\frac{g(r)}{\epsilon_0}\delta^{(3)}(\vec{r})$ in the differential equation. Your result should be something like
$$\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0r}\nabla^2g(r)-\frac{g(r)}{\epsilon_0}\delta^{(3)}(\vec{r})-\frac{1}{\lambda_D^2}\frac{g(r)}{4\pi\epsilon_0r}=-\frac{q_T}{\epsilon_0}\delta^{(3)}(\vec{r})$$
This yields an equation for $g(r)$ provided that $g(r=0)=q_T$ (as has been suggested by @kricheli in the comments). The aforesaid equation is
$$\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0r}\nabla^2g(r)=\frac{1}{\lambda_D^2}\frac{g(r)}{4\pi\epsilon_0r}\Rightarrow
\nabla^2g(r)=\frac{g(r)}{\lambda_D^2}$$
Then you can solve from there in spherical coordinates and fully specify $g(r)$. If there are still questions, please do not hesitate to ask